# Accessing the highWaterMark property of Nodejs stream in typescript gives: "Property '_readableState' does not exist" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

My question is about typescript and streams in nodejs. I wan't to extend the stream base class, and access the highWaterMark option.

In typescript, the following code works (i.e. the highWaterMark options is printed)

```
import * as stream from 'stream';

class ExampleStream extends stream.Readable {
  constructor() {
    super(options)
    console.log(this._readableState.highWaterMark)
  }

  _read() {}
  _write() {}
}
```

But typescript gives me the following error message regarding the line:

```
console.log(this._readableState.highWaterMark)
```

[ts] Property '_readableState' does not exist on type 'ExampleStream'.

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that [`_readableState`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/7629) is not exposed as part of the public API I don't think it will be/should be added to the node typings. To workaround this issue you can cast `this` to any and use the proeprties not available in node type definitions:

```
console.log((this as any)._readableState.highWaterMark)
```